Updated Indian tax returns
Suppose one needs to update ITR-2 filed for AY 2023-24 at a later time.
If in the updated return, the person has professional income (loss actually) and has to include schedule FA,
will the system allow him to file ITR-3 as the updated return instead (which, unlike ITR-2, allows for professional income declaration)?

You cannot disclose a loss in updated return.
